# Combine multiple html templates into single index.html file

Tags: html, gulp

I've been passed down a project built through Visual Studio and it contains an index.html.bundle file. In Visual Studio these files are usually built by running the build tool and this automatically creates the index.html page by combining all the template files inside the .bundle file.

However I am running this project on a Mac and can not get access to this tool.

I want to combine all the html templates into a singular index.html template, and was wondering if there is there a tool that can automate this (i.e. gulp, etc.)?

Comment: You can use [gulp-file-contents-to-keys](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-file-contents-to-keys)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure Gulp has a tool that will do this, but if you're just trying to combine files then `cat` will work fine:

```
cat index1.html index2.html index3.html > index.html
```

Comment: This solved my problem thank you now I just need to find a way to automate this.

Answer (score 5):

I found a gulp tool called [gulp-concat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-concat) that lets me automate this process as well. After installing, I put this into my gulpfile.js as a new task.

```
gulp.task('html', function() {
return gulp.src([
    'index1.html',
    'index2.html', 
    'index3.html'
])
.pipe(concat('index.html'))
.pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});
```